# How to re-order standard and link buttons in object list view?

Tags: community, salesforcedx, list-view

I would like to re-order the buttons in the Case list view.

[image]

Where:

- Change Owner - standard
- New - standard
- Create New Enquiry - Link
  Button

Here's the settings from Search layout:

[image]

My initial thought is that it isn't possible, but I'm just making sure that I did not miss anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right this feature is still not unavailable, as to why something this basic is missing I don't get it, the same can be done for record detail pages though

Do upvote the idea

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddohUAB/option-to-increasereorder-the-buttons-on-the-list-view-layout

Comment: I just found out that the standard buttons can be re-ordered. I don't know if its a bug or not. But the trick is to untick everything and then save. Then, check the first item you want to display and save. Then, check the next one and save.

Comment: That's a very crude fix, but whatever works nice find Carl

Answer (score 0):

I've found one work-around for this issue. We can un-select all the buttons and select in the order we want them to be in the list view layout!